# stop crashing all processes when one process crash in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, threadpool

I wrote a python code that calls a function "compute_cluster" in parallel with each call with difference parameters, however, one of these calls crashes which cause the rest of the processes to stop execution, now I want to know how to call my function in parallel and add some kind of exception such that when a process crashes I can know which parameters (C and L) caused this crash such that I can debug it while the rest of the processes keep running and not crash as well due to this specific call, the following is my script and any suggestions is highly appreciated:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def main():
         p = Pool(27)
         p.map(compute_cluster, [(l, r) for l in range(16, 25) for r in range(1, 4)])        
if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Comment: It may be easier if you stop using `map` and submit individual jobs.  Then you can store the return values (which represent the "future" result from those jobs), and iterate over them at the end to check their statuses.

Comment: I also have this problem. Is there any easy solution but still using `multiprocessing.pool`?